# Howcome my state is not updating using react hooks and use Effect

Tags: reactjs

My useEffect function is trying to fetch data from an API endpoint. The results resultAllTestTypes are currently logging fine.

However, I can't find out why the allTestTypes are coming back as undefined as I thought I had already set it in a state variable it should be able to log it to the console. But when I log the allTestTypes data it gives me this.

[image]

Code:

```
  const [allTestTypes, setAllTestTypes] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {

      const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
      const resultsAllTestTypes = await get('get_all_test_types', user.user)
      autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
      setAllTestTypes(resultsAllTestTypes)
  
      console.log('resultAllTestTypes data ',resultsAllTestTypes.data);

      console.log('allTestTypes data ',allTestTypes.data);


    }
    onLoadCreateUnitTests()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's setting the state, you just have a console.log in a spot that's not particularly useful.

`allTestTypes` is a local const. It will never change, and that's not what `setAllTestTypes` is trying to do. When you set state, this tells react to render the component again. When that render occurs, you'll make a new call to `useState`, which will return the new value and assign it to a new local const. That new variable can be interacted with by code in the new render, but code from the previous render (such as your console.log) will never see the new value.

If you'd like to verify that the component is rerendering with a new value, move your console.log into the body of the component:

```
const [allTestTypes, setAllTestTypes] = useState([])
console.log('Rendering with', allTestTypes);
useEffect(() => {
  async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {
    const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
    const resultsAllTestTypes = await get('get_all_test_types', user.user)
    autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
    setAllTestTypes(resultsAllTestTypes)
  }
  onLoadCreateUnitTests()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

cuz `setAllTestTypes` is async, so u can't get it immediately.
if u want to use it ,use the local variable `resultsAllTestTypes` instead